# iOS API in Parse - One to Many relation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, parse-platform

I am using [parse](https://parse.com/) for the backend part of my iPhone App.

We can have a one to many relation in Parse which described in [Relational Data](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects-pointers).

This code works fine to retrive the data:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Comment"];
PFObject *fetchedComment = [query getObjectWithId:@"0PprArjYi3"];

NSString *content = [fetchedComment objectForKey:@"content"];
printf("%s", [content UTF8String]);
```

But when I use their codes provided in the Link, it returns null:

```
PFObject *post = [fetchedComment objectForKey:@"parent"];
[post fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
          title = [post objectForKey:@"title"];
}];
printf("%s", [title UTF8String]);     // RETURN NULL
```

Can anybody tell me what is wrong in this code? **The problem could be fetchedcomment**.

---

Addenda

This one also got an exception:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Comment"];
PFObject *fetchedComment = [query getObjectWithId:@"0PprArjYi3"];

PFObject *post = [fetchedComment objectForKey:@"parent"];
NSString *title = [post objectForKey:@"title"];
printf("%s", [title UTF8String]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock` is, as the name suggests, performed in background. Your code asks for a fetch and then immediately continues to the `printf`. At that point in time, the data hasn't been fetched yet, so `title` is probably still `nil`.

You have two options -

1. Use a synchronous method, such as [post fetch]: instead of [parent fetchInBackground...].

   ```
   [post fetch];
   title1 = [post objectForKey:@"title"];
   ```
2. Print the title inside the block that gets executed when the `fetchInBackground...` method finishes.

Comment: I appreciate for your answer, but I tried that also, an exception happend. look at my new edit please. Can you help me?

Comment: You're not fetching now at all. `[query getObjectWithId]` gets you an live object, but its `parent` attribute just contains the ID of the live object in Parse. You still have to fetch it, like in the original code you provided. Try changing `fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock` to `fetch`.

Comment: Also, you said "I tried that also". What did you try? I haven't suggested a course of action, only explanation for why your code fails.

Comment: Check what I added to the end of my question. I did not use fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock.

Comment: But you must use some kind of `fetch`; use your original code, change `fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock` to `fetch`. Also, if my answer isn't clear, tell me.

Comment: No it is not clear, if you know the code, can you add it to the end of your answer. thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17016/discussion-between-ali-and-user1071136)